# DAX How calculate last 4 month from month was choice on month slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do you calculate the last 4 months from month was choice on month slicer ?

if choice month 10 in slicer I want to see sum amount for moths 10,9,8,7 only

calculate (
[sumAmount],
????
)

thanks

Comment: Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Let - your slicer generating from table "Dates" and the column name is "Date". Considering this, you can go for a measures as below to achieve your required output-

**Measure: 1**

```
4_month_start_date = 
VAR start_of_selected_month = STARTOFMONTH(Dates[Date])
VAR start_of_4_month = EDATE(start_of_selected_month,-3)

RETURN start_of_4_month
```

**Measure: 2**

```
4_month_end_date = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[date])
```

**Measure: 3**

```
4_month_sum = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table[sumAmount]),
    DATESBETWEEN
    (
        'Dates'[Date],
        [4_month_start_date],
        [4_month_end_date]
    )
)
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Hi mkRabbani
this give me next 4 months, but i need previus 4 months... When I change -3 to 3 this give me only 1 month

Comment: This should give you correct output. anyway, I have separated one measures into 3 measure now. Please go through. You can also check what start and end date returning first based on your selected date.

Comment: Last versiom better, but this make cumulative sum of 4 monts, and no per month.

Comment: great, this means we are close. Now please add some sample data and your expected results from them. This will help to resolve the issue.